# how to get the whole name of person from database

Tags: sql, oracle11g, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have these tables

**person**  table with following data

```
person_id    description

 1          first in the family
 2          second in the family
 3          third in the family
 4          fourth int the family
 5          fifth in the family
```

---

**person_name** table with following data

```
person_id  first_name

  1        Santiago
  2         Lautaro
  3          Lucas
  4          Franco
  5          Agustín
```

**father** table with following data

```
person_father_id  description
    1              father of Lautaro
    2              father of Lucas
    3              father of Franco
    4              father of Agustín
```

---

**children** table with following data

```
 person_child_id   person_father_id
      2                 1
      3                 2
      4                 3
      5                 4
```

---

how to get full name (Agustín Franco Lucas Lautaro Santiago) of person where person_id 4 in select pl/sql query. the core table is person

Comment: Why is Agustín included in the result - shouldn't it start from Franco, as that is ID 4? (Your data model is a bit odd, not sure why you have `person_name` rather than just having the name as part of `person`, and the `father` table doesn't seem to be doing anything? And do you really want/need a PL/SQL solution when this can be done in SQL?)

Comment: @Alex Poole .right it should start from Franco . every person has his own properties in separated tables like name and gender and date and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a hierarchical query with an inline view that joins the relevant tables together first. The query for the inline view could be:

```
select p.person_id, pn.first_name, c.person_father_id
from person p
join person_name pn on pn.person_id = p.person_id
left join children c on c.person_child_id = p.person_id;

 PERSON_ID FIRST_NAME PERSON_FATHER_ID
---------- ---------- ----------------
         2 Lautaro                   1
         3 Lucas                     2
         4 Franco                    3
         5 Agustín                   4
         1 Santiago
```

and with that as the basis for a hierarchical query:

```
select trim(sys_connect_by_path(first_name, ' ')) as whole_name
from (
  select p.person_id, pn.first_name, c.person_father_id
  from person p
  join person_name pn on pn.person_id = p.person_id
  left join children c on c.person_child_id = p.person_id
)
where connect_by_isleaf = 1
start with person_id = 4
connect by person_id = prior person_father_id;

WHOLE_NAME                                        
--------------------------------------------------
Franco Lucas Lautaro Santiago
```

Or you could make the hierarchical query itself a further subquery, and then join to the names afterwards and aggregate that:

```
select listagg(pn.first_name, ' ') within group (order by lvl) as whole_name
from (
  select person_id, level as lvl
  from (
    select p.person_id, c.person_father_id
    from person p
    left join children c on c.person_child_id = p.person_id
  )
  start with person_id = 4
  connect by person_id = prior person_father_id
) t
join person_name pn on pn.person_id = t.person_id;

WHOLE_NAME                                        
--------------------------------------------------
Franco Lucas Lautaro Santiago
```

Notice that with both of those you have to join the tables before you can filter based on your starting ID (`start with` rather than `where`, as this is hierarchical). That means that with larger tables it could end up doing more work than you really need or expect.

Or you could do the same thing with recursive subquery factoring (a recursive CTE) if you prefer, and you are using Oracle 11gR2 or higher:

```
with r (person_id, person_father_id, lvl) as (
  select p.person_id, c.person_father_id, 1
  from person p
  left join children c on c.person_child_id = p.person_id
  where p.person_id = 4
  union all
  select p.person_id, c.person_father_id, r.lvl + 1
  from r
  join person p on p.person_id = r.person_father_id
  left join children c on c.person_child_id = p.person_id
)
select listagg(pn.first_name, ' ') within group (order by lvl) as whole_name
from r
join person_name pn on pn.person_id = r.person_id;

WHOLE_NAME                                        
--------------------------------------------------
Franco Lucas Lautaro Santiago
```

which looks more complicated but can at least put the filter in the anchor member of the recursive CTE.

Read more about [hierarchical queries](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Hierarchical-Queries.html) and [recursive subquery factoring](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6).

Comment: I would strongly recommend CTEs over [old school] `CONNECT BY`. The latter is dying (though still supported) and found nowhere else apart from Oracle.